# i m trying to find a query that select * from my table where it will find the same data inputed for same column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
name     frnds     city     country    job     age
a        aa       dehradun    india     xyz    23
b        bbb      delhi       india     abc    23
c        cc       paris       france    sdc    45
d        dd       berlin      germany   der    19
e        ee       dehradun    india     dec    20
f        ff       delhi       yog       cdfr   43
```

suppose this is my table and I want to find out the city name and the country name where (both) are same.

result should be like this

```
name   frnds   city     country   job     age
a      aa      dehradun    india     xyz   23
e      ee      dehradun    india     dec   20
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: i wrote it complicated bt plz check this

Comment: i am using mysql database

Comment: Is there only one city, country duplicated?

Comment: no, there can be many

Answer (score 1):

One way is to group by `city` and `country` and find groups that have more than one member:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable t
WHERE EXISTS(
   SELECT city, country
   FROM MyTable t2
   WHERE t2.city = t1.city
     AND t2.country = t1.country
   GROUP BY city, country
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you calculate the list of duplicate `city, country` once, and join back to your original table.

You should consider create one composite index with `city, country`

```
 SELECT A.*
 FROM yourtable A
 JOIN (SELECT city, country
       FROM yourtable
       GROUP BY city, country
       HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
     ) as duplicate
 ON  A.city = duplicate.city
 AND A.country = duplicate.country
 ORDER BY A.city, A.country;
```